What does ´added twist´ mean?
in the sentence :
He performed his experiments with patients , this time with an added twist . it differs from ´with a twist´

Have you tried looking up "twist" in a dictionary?

This question is similar to: What does the expression "With a twist" means?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. "Added" is also in dictionaries.

Please explain more about why you think that adding the word "added" makes a significant difference. I think you can get better answers if we address your misunderstanding rather than the phrase itself.

With an added twist implies that some twist has already been there, and that the one in question is now added to it. In the actual use of the phrase, however, there is often no indication what that pre-existing twist might be, which raises a question what role, if any, added plays. That is a question that is not answered by explaining what with a twist means by itself.
